# count how often a piece of information appears and calculate that average

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I do not want to know the traditional frequency or the traditional averages; so I'll give an example below:

I have this data:
1
3
5
5
2
3
5
5
1
3

[image: original data 1]

The analysis that I would like to obtain is the following:

for example number 1 appears once every eight rows, number 3 appears once every four rows, number 5 appears twice every two rows....

[image: analisis]

**I did it by hand, but now I have more than 21000 rows of data and I'm stuck.**

I searched but I can not find a function that does it; But before I started developing my own, I decided to ask for a guide on how to achieve it.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no function or functionallity to do what you are trying to achieve. Searching this kind of variable patterns can be quite complex. Of course it can be done by using VBA but it is not an easy one that  somebody will build for free. You may go to a freelancers site or you can create some code and that should find the requested patterns add to your question and somebody may guide you to find them (also not clear what kind of patterns may find).

Comment: I cannot think of any function that will accomplish this kind of pattern matching, and that you'll have to write the function yourself. It looks to be fairly easy to accomplish though.

Comment: Could you please post a larger sample and output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I was able to achieve the desired result:

[image: test1]
[image: test2]
[image: test3]
The formula is:

[image: test4]
  Or, if you want to copy/paste:

```
=IF(CONCATENATE("1-",MATCH(D1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(D1,A1:A17,0)+1,1,4)&":A17"),0))="1-1",CONCATENATE("2-",MATCH(D1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(D1,A1:A17,0)+2,1,4)&":A17"),0)-1),CONCATENATE("1-",MATCH(D1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(D1,A1:A17,0)+1,1,4)&":A17"),0)))
```

Note that the IF function solves the duplicates (like the number 5). In case you have triplicates you will have to add another instance of IF and adjust the formula accordingly.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Well this doesn't exactly reproduce your results, but you could start by looking at the max and min separation of the numbers:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)<=1,"",MIN(IF((ROW(A$1:INDEX(A$1:A$10,COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)+1))>1)
*(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A$1:A$10,COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)+1))<=COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)),
FREQUENCY(IF(A$1:A$10<>C2,ROW(A$1:A$10)),IF(A$1:A$10=C2,ROW(A$1:A$10)))))+1)

=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)<=1,"",MAX(IF((ROW(A$1:INDEX(A$1:A$10,COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)+1))>1)
*(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A$1:A$10,COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)+1))<=COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,C2)),
FREQUENCY(IF(A$1:A$10<>C2,ROW(A$1:A$10)),IF(A$1:A$10=C2,ROW(A$1:A$10)))))+1)
```

[image]

This gives the min or max number of rows between each occurrence of the particular number.

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could add other statistics (like mean, standard deviation) the same way although the average could be calculated just by (lastrow-firstrow)/(count-1) e.g. for 5 it would be (8-3)/(4-1)=5/3.